# POST request in controller for custom contact form via AJAX

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I've build a custom form which action redirects to a confirm page. In the controller of this page I get the `POST` values via `$request->request->get('fieldName');`

To enhance the user experience I'd like to stay on the same page as the form and add a success message to the page. I guess this can be done via AJAX? I tried to follow this [guide](https://shopwarian.com/how-to-send-a-post-request-to-the-controller/?amp) since it kind of seems to describe what I'm trying to achieve, but I struggle to understand the [custom component](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/add-custom-component) part. It seems this is only for the backend?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The guide you shared is about the `administration`, if you want to add your functionality to the `storefront` instead you should be able to follow [this guide](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-dynamic-content-via-ajax-calls).

For an overview of how the `administration` and `storefront` differs, you can read up the concepts behind those two areas [here](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/concepts/framework/architecture).

Comment: Thx, I got the plugin running but I still don't get how I would fetch the data submitted by the form and then pass it to the controller.

Comment: There is no shopware magic behind it, if you use the `<form>` html element, with the correct url as the `action` tag all the provided values inside the form will automatically be sent to the server on submit of that form. And in you controller you can access this data via `$request->request->get()`.

Comment: Yes, but I mean via AJAX.